# How to make a scrollbar appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

Here's what I'm trying to make. I want a div which appears as a box of fixed dimensions, into which various javascript functions will be placing text over time. When the number of lines of text exceeds the height of the box, I'd like a scrollbar to appear alongside the box, so that you can scroll through the text inside it while the box itself remains a fixed height.

How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using css you can do this:

```
div{
   overflow-y: scroll
}
```

you can also  `overflow-y: auto` as @tw16

Comment: Something I was looking for for a long time. Thanks!

Comment: To add `overflow-y: auto` to your answer after I had answered is a bit cheeky.

Comment: No, any method was acceptable. I tagged it with everything I'm somewhat familiar with and thus would be willing to use. This works quite well.

Answer (score 4):

As you say the scrollbar should only appear when there is too much text, I would use:

```
div{
    overflow-y: auto
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/RMpFu/

Answer (score 3):

Use `overflow` in CSS:

```
document.querySelector("div").style.overflowY = "scroll";  //For Y
document.querySelector("div").style.overflowX = "scroll";  //For X

document.querySelector("div").style.overflow = "scroll";   //For both ;)
```

### P.S.

If you want it to show the scroll bar only when necessary, you can do this instead:

```
document.querySelector("div").style.overflow = "auto";    //JavaScript

//-or-

div{
    overflow: auto;                       /*CSS*/
}
```

Comment: Why are you applying everything to the `body` and not the `div` the OP refers to?

Comment: @tw16 - Referring to `body` in JavaScript is much easier than a `div`... It's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
   $('.holeEvent').hover(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('holeEvent').addClass('holeEvent2');
   },
   function(){
      $(this).removeClass('holeEvent2').addClass('holeEvent');
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.holeEvent {
   height: 50px;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
.holeEvent2 {
   height: 50px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>

<div class="holeEvent2"></div>
```